# Solve the differential equation with given conditions $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{4x\ln(x)}{t},\ x(1)=3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation using initial condition $x(1) = 3$.

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{4x\ln(x)}{t}$$

This is a homework problem.

I've tried separation of variables.

$$ \dfrac{dx}{x\ln(x)}= \dfrac{4dt}{t}$$

From here,  taking the integral of both sides I end up with...,

$$ \ln(\ln|x|) = 4\ln(t) + C$$

Now, since it's a double ln, I'm guessing we need to raise it to $e$ twice.
\begin{align*}e^{\ln(\ln|x|)} &= e^{4\ln(t)}+ e^C\\
\ln(|x|) &= t^4 + e^C \end{align*}
One more time...,
$$ x = e^{t^4 + e^C}= e^{t^4}e^{e^c}$$ is it right so far?

Initial values are $x(1) = 3$, so
$$ 3 = e^1e^{e^c}$$ so i end up with
$$\ln(3) - 1 = e^c$$

So the particular solution is then, 
$$x = e^{t^4}e^{\ln(3)-1}$$
This is being graded as incorrect, so where did I go wrong?

Comment: $e^{4 \ln t + C} \neq e^{4 \ln t} + e^C$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the identity $$e^{a+b}=e^a e^b$$ we have the following:

$$\ln(\ln|x|) = 4 \ln(t) + C$$
$$ e^{\ln (\ln|x|)} = e^{4 \ln(t)+C} \Rightarrow \ln(|x|) = e^{\ln{(t^4)}} \cdot e^C \Rightarrow \ln(|x|) = t^4\cdot e^C$$

$C'=e^C$
$$ e^{\ln(|x|)} = e^{C' t^4} \Rightarrow x =  e^{C't^4}$$

$x(1) = 3:$

$$ 3 = e^{C'} \Rightarrow \ln{3}  = C'$$

Therefore, 
$$x(t) = e^{\ln 3 \cdot t^4} \Rightarrow \left( e^{\ln 3} \right )^{t^4}=3^{t^4}$$

Answer (score 2):

When you have $\ln |x| = 4\ln t + C$ and exponentiate, you should get:

$|x| = e^{4\ln t + C} = e^{C}e^{4\ln t} = e^Ct^4$ instead of $t^4 + e^C$.

In general, after you solve a differential equation, its a good idea to check to make sure the solution you found does indeed satisfy the differential equation.

If $x = Ke^{t^4}$, then $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 4Kt^3e^{t^4}$ but $\dfrac{4x\ln x}{t} = \dfrac{4Ke^{t^4}\ln(Ke^{t^4})}{t} = \dfrac{4Ke^{t^4}(t^4+\ln K)}{t} $.